# Why Does Microsoft Use The Word 'Proxy'?

Tags: user-profile-service, service

Could somebody explain the use of the word 'proxy' in service applications in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 in simple understandable terms?

*A Proxy Group is a mechanism which defines the relationship between a web application and the proxy (or connection) for a service application. This proxy enables the web applications associated with the Proxy Group to consume services (Managed Metadata, Search, User Profiles, etc.) from the service application.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word "proxy" and "proxy-group" is a bit misleading and should be called something like "Service Application Connection" and "Service Application Connection Group".

The connection between a web-application and a service application is through a Proxy group, so it's the way a web-application communicates and consume a service application.

I think that this blog explains it in simple terms, and got a lot of pictures in addition to the explanation.

[SharePoint 2010 Service Application](http://arkaysps.blogspot.se/2010/08/share-point-2010-service-application.html)

[image]

Comment: I think that even the word group is misleading too because when you create multiple service applications of the same type e.g. Excel Service App 1 and Excel Service App 2 then do not show as being in the same group in the Service Applications list in Central Admin.

Comment: I did not understand that. When creating a service application you can choose ( and for some services must ) to add it to the default proxy group. Can you try to explain what you mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

A service connection (**“proxy”** in Windows PowerShell) is the logical element that
connects a Web application to a specific instance of a service. Administrators do not
need to create or manage these. Some connections have settings that can be
configured by administrators, for example, the Business Data Connectivity connection

When you create a service application, a connection for the service application is created at the same time. A connection is a virtual entity that connects Web applications to service applications. In Windows PowerShell, these connections are called proxies. "Proxy" appears at the end of the type description for connections on the Manage Service Applications page in Central Administration

read more over here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/5/2E54AB34-2AB4-4779-9C61-1370381FEF67/SvsSingleFarm_SharePointProducts2010.pdf

Comment: Why should administrators not create and manage these? I think it's a good thing that we can create our own proxy groups with PowerShell and name them, keeping the groups structured and relevant to the different web applications.

Comment: I am not sure why but their could many reason one of them is complex structure.

Comment: One powershell cmdlt to rule them all. :) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607660(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: perfect....i am not aware this....but MSFT says dont need to manage & create....be safe